# Return a generic Traversable of a specified type

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections, type-parameter

I'd like to be able to generically manipulate types like `T[_] <: Traversable` so that I can do things like map and filter, but I'd like to defer the decision about which `Traversable` I select for as long as possible.

I'd like to be able write functions against a generic `T[Int]` that return a `T[Int]` not a `Traversable[Int]`. So for example, I'd like to apply a function to a `Set[Int]` or a `Vector[Int]` or anything that extends Traversable and get that type back.

I first attempted to do this in a simple manner like:

```
trait CollectionHolder[T[_] <: Traversable[_]] {

  def easyLessThanTen(xs: T[Int]): T[Int] = {
    xs.filter(_ < 10)
  }
}
```

but this won't compile: Missing parameter type for expanded function. It will compile, however, if the function takes a `Traversable[Int]` instead of a `T[Int]`, so thought I could work with `Traversable` and convert to a `T`. This lead me to `CanBuildFrom`

```
object DoingThingsWithTypes {    

  trait CollectionHolder[T[_] <: Traversable[_]] {

    def lessThanTen(xs: T[Int])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Traversable[Int], Int, T[Int]]): T[Int] = {

      val filteredTraversable = xs.asInstanceOf[Traversable[Int]].filter(_ < 10)

      (cbf() ++= filteredTraversable).result
}
```

which compiles. But then in my tests:

```
val xs = Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 1000)

object withSet extends CollectionHolder[Set]

withSet.lessThanTen(xs) shouldBe Set(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I get the following compiler error:

> Cannot construct a collection of type Set[Int] with elements of type
>   Int based on a collection of type Traversable[Int]. not enough
>   arguments for method lessThanTen: (implicit cbf:
>   scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Traversable[Int],Int,Set[Int]])Set[Int].
>   Unspecified value parameter cbf.

Where can I get a CanBuildFrom to make this conversion? Or better yet, how can I modify my simpler approach for the result I want? Or do I need to use a typeclass and write an implicit implementation for each Traversable I'm interested in using (one for Set, one for Vector etc)? I'd prefer to avoid the last approach if possible.

Comment: I would suggest using an even higher abstraction like the `Functor` **typeclass**.

Comment: Can you expand on that thought a bit?

Comment: I mean that, instead of trying to use the collections library and the build from and all that. You may just write your code in terms of `Functor.map` and things like that. If you have no experience with that you may start by reading scala-with-cats. Also, if you can provide a concrete example with all the methods your require I would be able to provide an implementation.

Comment: A final implementation would have a fairly large number of methods that use things like: filter, exists, and nonEmpty (thus using Traversable). If I need to write a new typeclass for each of the Traversables I'll use (Set, Vector etc), for every function it seems like I may as well leave them abstract and implement everything for each traversable. 

My hope was to have most of the functions be built on top of a small number of abstract functions so implementing this for a new type just meant writing a small number of functions, and all the rest would come for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the (Scala 2.12.8) standard library instead of cats/scalaz/etc. you need to look at [`GenericTraversableTemplate`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/generic/GenericTraversableTemplate.html). `filter` isn't defined there, but can easily be:

```
import scala.collection.GenTraversable
import scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate

trait CollectionHolder[T[A] <: GenTraversable[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, T]] {

  def lessThanTen(xs: T[Int]): T[Int] = {
    filter(xs)(_ < 10)
  }

  def filter[A](xs: T[A])(pred: A => Boolean) = {
    val builder = xs.genericBuilder[A]
    xs.foreach(x => if (pred(x)) { builder += x })
    builder.result()
  }
}
```

In the comment you mention `nonEmpty` and `exists`; they are available because of the `GenTraversable` type bound. Really `filter` is too, the problem is that it returns `GenTraversable[A]` instead of `T[A]`.

Scala 2.13 reworks collections so the methods will probably be slightly different there, but I haven't looked enough at it yet.

Also: `T[_] <: Traversable[_]` is likely not what you want as opposed to `T[A] <: Traversable[A]`; e.g. the first constraint is not violated if you have `T[Int] <: Traversable[String]`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am saying that you should use **typeclasses**.
But, you do not have to implement them, nor provide their instances for the types you need. As, those are very common and can be found in *libraries* like `cats` or `scalaz`.

For example, using `cats`:

```
import cats.{Traverse, TraverseFilter}
import cats.syntax.all._ // Provides the nonEmpty, filter & map extension methods to C.

import scala.language.higherKinds

def algorithm[C[_]: TraverseFilter: Traverse](col: C[Int]): C[Int] =
  if (col.nonEmpty)
    col.filter(x => x < 10)
  else
    col.map(x => x * 2) // nonsense, but just to show that you can use map too.
```

Which you can use like this:

```
import cats.instances.list._

algorithm(List(1, 200, 3, 100))
// res: List[Int] = List(1, 3)
```

It may be worth adding, that there are a lot of other methods like `exists`, `foldLeft`, `size`, etc.
Take a look to the [**documentation**](https://typelevel.org/cats/). And if it is your first time using either `cats` or `scalaz` or those concepts in general, you may find [scala-with-cats](https://underscore.io/books/scala-with-cats/) very instructive.

Comment: TraverseFilter looks exactly like what I was looking for, thanks. I am already using a few Cats Typeclasses (Monad, Functor). Can you help me understand the syntax here: "C[_]: TraverseFilter: Traverse". It looks like a type parameter whose type also has a type? I don't think I've seen this before.

Comment: `def algo[C[_]: TraverseFilter: Traverse]` is equivalent to `def algo[C[_]](implicit ev1: TraverseFilter[C], ev2: Traverse[C])`. So basically, it is asking for implicit parameters. More specifically a **typeclass** instance for the given type parameter - it is called [_context bounds_](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html).